# How to import object to another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node.js to build a web application.

I have two files. Server.js - where I call the server to go online etc. And the other one is a file which includes a big object with data. I imported the file with data into server.js, I get the object in postman when I set the website to be live. But I can't dive inside the object to get the data inside the object. The error I'm getting says that the variable where my data is stored is not defined.

I think the fix is to import albumsData variable into server.js, but im completely stuck and can't find how to do it. If anyone has any idea, please share.

albumsData.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

let albumsData = {
filled with data
}

router.get('/albumData', (req, res) => {
    res.send(albumsData);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Server.js

```
app.use(require('./api/albumData/unikkatilData'))

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404)
    .send(albumsData)
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('hello worldd')
})
```

Comment: Was the other file a .json file?

Comment: It's a javascript file.

Comment: can you show the code for the import of the data?

Comment: It shows in the server.js, I believe?

Comment: This is my full albumsData.js file - https://pastebin.com/yJavMYMG?fbclid=IwAR0IsTzYlb2ck6lNPwyS2Db9OdOpLiSN3Y6nZCRv1M_OvAQ_MsGCa8zk1Lk

Comment: Okay, we don't require things like this in node.

Comment: you can use `require` for importing modules or even an array/object.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the `albumsData` object then you can do it like this:

In you albumsData.js file:

```
const albumsData = {
    // Bunch of data
}

module.exports = albumsData
```

Then in your server.js file:

```
const albumData = require('./api/albumsData') // Make sure this path points directly to the albumsData.js file
```

Answer (score 1):

move  `enter code here` to new file (ex utils.js)
 and export it `exports.albumsData = albumsData;` then you can call it
with `const utils = require('./utils') ; utils.albumsData`